Decomposition of non-finitely generated modules over a finite dimensional algebra, $A$, where $A$ is of finite representation type.
Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over some field $k$ and of finite representation type. A finite dimensional algebra $A$ is said to be of finite representation type, or of finite type for short, if there is only a finite number of indecomposable objects up to isomorphism in the category of finitely generated modules over $A$. Let $\{ M_1,...,M_n \}$ be a complete set of representatives of the
isomorphism classes of indecomposable modules for the algebra $A$.
As is well known, since $A$ is of finite representation type, any finitely generated module $M$ over the algebra $A$ can be decomposed as $$M \simeq {M_1}^{(k_1)} \oplus {M_2}^{(k_2)}\oplus \cdots \oplus{M_n}^{(k_n)} ,$$ where $0\leq k_i \in \mathbb{N}, \ 1 \leq i \leq n$.
This naturally raises the question：When $M$ is a non-finitely generated module over $A$ where $A$ is of finite representation type, can we also conclude that $$M \simeq {M_1}^{(k_1)} \oplus {M_2}^{(k_2)}\oplus \cdots \oplus{M_n}^{(k_n)} ,$$ where $0\leq k_i \in (\mathbb{N} \bigcup \infty), \ 1 \leq i \leq n$?

If $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ are different infinite cardinals, then the direct sum of $\kappa$ copies of $M_i$ is different from the direct sum of $\lambda$ copies. So you should let $k_i$ be any cardinal, as $M_i^\infty$ doesn't really make sense unless you specify which $\infty$. Also, the standard meaning of $M_i^{\kappa_i}$ is the direct product of $\kappa_i$ copies of $M_i$, with $M_i^{(\kappa_i)}$ used for the direct sum.
But subject to these slight clarifications, then yes, if a finite dimensional algebra has finite representation type, with indecomposable finite dimensional modules $M_1,\dots,M_n$, then every $A$-module, whether or not it is finitely generated, is isomorphic to
$$M_1^{(\kappa_1)}\oplus\dots\oplus M_n^{(\kappa_n)}$$
for some (uniquely determined) cardinals $\kappa_1, \dots,\kappa_n$.
This was proved in Corollary 4.8 of
Auslander, Maurice, Representation theory of Artin algebras. II, Commun. Algebra 1, 269-310 (1974). ZBL0285.16029.
and independently in Corollary 4.4 of
Ringel, Claus Michael; Tachikawa, Hiroyuki, QF-3 rings, J. Reine Angew. Math. 272, 49-72 (1975). ZBL0318.16006.

Thank you so much for your assistance; I truly appreciate your expertise!
